# Data Science: What is the best way to figure out the correlation between multiple characteristics and a performance score?

Tags: python, statistics, data-science

I am very new to data science, so I have a (basic?) question:

I have a set of materials (let's say plastics, glass, concrete…). I have a bunch of characteristics of each material (e.g. toughness, translucency) and for each of these materials I also have a score how they perform in a certain test.
Now I want to find out if there is some kind of correlation between the characteristics and the performance score. There is no linear correlation, I assume that it some combination of some (but not all) of the characteristics.

How do I go about finding out how they are "connected" ? What are the best methods? I was thinking of training a neural network but I don't have that much data and also, it seems like a bit of an overkill.

As I said I am very new to this so I am grateful for any hint or term I need to search for (I work with Python, btw).

Comment: Hey there - please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section and edit your question to enable responders to help you out, e.i. give some basic data, information on what you have tried and references to material you have found.

Comment: Have you try to check the correlation matrix of the data (that would be my starting point)? How many samples of each material you have?

Comment: @LucasM.Uriarte: Thank you! Yes, I've tried that but there was no direct correlation between any of the input characteristics and the test score which is why I assume that it must be some kind of combination. The data consists of one "dataset" per material but that was obtained by taking the average of 8 samples, if I remeber correctly.

Comment: @JakobGuldbergAaes I know the question is far from perfect but at the moment I don't even know where to start because I most probably lack the right terms to even properly search. ^^°

Comment: @Crazy Engineer, to calculate the correlation matrix I will used the original data not the 8 samples average. With no correlation you mean you have all values to zero? secondly, are we talking about pearson correlation matrix?

Comment: @LucasM.Uriarte Ah, maybe that's the problem. I will ask for the raw data of all samples and try it again. Thank you for the hint!

Comment: Alternative install dtale and make an exploratory analysis - 0 code needed :D

Answer (score 0):

To find correlation between characteristics of your materials and their performance in a certain test,you can try to use machine learning algorithms like a decision tree or a random forest. its simple to use with even less data.
you need to experiments different algorithms to find best approach that works for you.

Comment: Though the question lacked specifics this answer would be vastly improved with a short and sweet example, inline. See [How to write a good answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).